# Which programming languages can I use with Unity?

Tags: unity

I'm familiar with Unity and most of its features, but I don't know which programming languages are supported. I think it uses C#, which I'm unfamiliar with, so I was wondering if Unity supports any other languages.

Comment: So, you were unable to find this? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html

Comment: Thanks yeah that was fairly dumb of me not to look at the Unity manual.

Comment: This question was useful to me, I did initially bump into docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html however it left me undecided if c# was the only language Unity's available in. A quick web search brought me here and cleared that up wonders, I don't think the question should have down votes.

Answer (score 6):

In the time since this question was first asked, the **UnityScript** and **Boo** options in Unity have been deprecated, and are no longer available in current Unity versions.

(This is one reason why questions about the supported features of a particular software package aren't a great fit for the Q&A format we use here - old information can fossilize. Your first port of call should always be the documentation for that software itself, which will generally have the most up-to-date information about what it does and does not support)

[The Unity documentation now reads](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html):

> Unity supports the **C#** programming language natively. C# (pronounced C-sharp) is an industry-standard language similar to Java or C++.
>
> In addition to this, many other .NET languages can be used with Unity if they can compile a compatible DLL - see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) for further details.

Comment: Feel free to instead just update existing answers in cases like this.

Answer (score 3):

As found in [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html), there is one "native" choice:

> - **C#** (pronounced C-sharp), an industry-standard language similar to Java

Additionally, many other .NET compatible languages (like C++) can be used, [if they are first compiled into a DLL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) (then you'd have to write wrapper code in C#).